# React inline function in render with mobx

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Can I use `bind` function in render with mobx? I know that this practice leads to performance degradation, but my colleague says that if we use `mobx` we can do `bind` function in render

Example:

```
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react'

@inject('store')
@observer
export default class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {
      store: {
        pushByPath,
      },
    } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => pushByPath('param1')}
        />
        <button
          onClick={() => pushByPath('param2')}
        />
        <button
          onClick={() => pushByPath('param3')}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: It helps if you could share your end goal/what are you trying to do here. `bind` is javascript specific feature to play around with instances.

Comment: Main question was does the mobx save you from `bind` problem inside render

Answer (score 0):

if you need your function `pushByPath` to be bound to an instance of a store, you may follow such pattern:

```
import {action} from 'mobx';

class Store {

   @action.bound pushByPath(path) {
       // this here will always point to an instance of Store
   }
}
```

Actually, you can use `bind` and really recreating function is a performance hit, but really very minimal for modern browsers. And it does not matter do you use `mobx` or not.